# Google mail servers returing Deffered: 450-4.2.1. for no apparent reason

Tags: email-server, sendmail, gmail, email-bounces

We have a problem with our sendmail: gmail is always returning the "Deffered: 450-4.2.1." error.

I checked all available documents and help articles, but it only confuses me. I am testing this on my own email, and surely I do not receive more then the limit. Emails from other places are received without any problems.

Is there anything we could do on our server to fix this?

best regards and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en

- 450, "4.2.1" The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail too quickly. Please resend your message at a later time. If the user is able to receive mail at that time, your message will be delivered. For more information, review this article.
- 450, "4.2.1", The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that prevents additional messages from being delivered. Please resend your message at a later time. If the user is able to receive mail at that time, your message will be delivered. For more information, review this article.
- 450, "4.2.1", Peak SMTP relay limit exceeded for customer. This is a temporary error. For more information on SMTP relay limits, please contact your administrator or review this article.

None of these are likely to be things you can affect.

Comment: I saw that, buy somehow it seems highly unlikely that only our mail server has this issue; that's why I want to keep trying to change something on server-side

Comment: What makes you think that only your email server experiences this?

Comment: @joeqwerty I receive about 80 (non-spam) emails per day; somebody  would tell me if there is something wrong. I also asked people to bombard me with emails when the error occurs, and I receive every one of them.